# How do I return the value of a matching vector in to a new column?

Tags: r

I want to return the value city_df[3,2] in a new column (in the same row as the matching vector value) because it matches with city_df[1,1]. How can I do this without using the actual names, it needs to be generalizable because I have to use it on a huge dataset. With other words: I need help with how to add the column "name3".

```
    name <- c("City1", "City2", "City3", "City4", "City5")
    name2 <- c("City6", "City7", "City1", "City9", "City10")
    name3 <- c("City1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA") ## I need help to create this column...

city_df <- data.frame(name, name2, name3 )

city_df
```

Desired output:

```
  name  name2 name3
1 City1  City6 City1
2 City2  City7    NA
3 City3  City1    NA
4 City4  City9    NA
5 City5 City10    NA
```

I have tried loops, ifelse, etc. but with no luck.I only manage to return if the vector name are in the colum (using %in%).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dplyr`'s `left_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)

city_df %>% 
  left_join(city_df, by = c("name" = "name2"), suffix = c("", ".y"), keep = TRUE) %>% 
  select(name, name2, name3 = name2.y)
```

This returns

```r
   name  name2 name3
1 City1  City6 City1
2 City2  City7  <NA>
3 City3  City1  <NA>
4 City4  City9  <NA>
5 City5 City10  <NA>
```

Another possibility could be

```r
city_df$name3 <- ifelse(city_df$name %in% city_df$name2, city_df$name, NA_character_)
```

creating the same output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect`, conveniently with `do.call`, since `df[1:2]` is already a list. To prevent recycling, we cann fill with `NA` using `` `length<-` ``.

```
city_df$name3 <- `length<-`(do.call(intersect, unname(city_df[1:2])), nrow(city_df))
city_df
#    name  name2 name3
# 1 City1  City6 City1
# 2 City2  City7  <NA>
# 3 City3  City1  <NA>
# 4 City4  City9  <NA>
# 5 City5 City10  <NA>
```